# jquery ui slidetoggle animation not working properly in FireFox

Tags: jquery-ui, firefox, slidetoggle

Consider this minimalistic standalone example using jQuery.ui slidetoggle:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Toggle Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#fold').click(function () {
                $('.inner').slideToggle(2000);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fold">+-</div>
<div class="inner">
    TESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTEST<br/>
    TESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTEST<br/>
    TESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTEST<br/>
    TESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTEST<br/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Expected behavior: clicking on the `#fold` element collapses the `.inner` element with a 2-second animation (changing the height).

This works when I load the page in Firefox for the first time.
However, as soon as I open the Dom-Inspector in Firefox and select for example the `.inner` element the behavior changes:
A click will result in changing the element's display to none after 2 seconds (as before) but the animation is gone.
In chrome everything is alright.

Note1:
I am using FF33.0 from the ubuntu reps.
When trying to reproduce this with jsfiddle, make sure, that the content of the lower-right Iframe is actually displayed in the DOM-Inspector.

Note2:
I am working on a JSON editor and came across this issue when trying to implement fold-marks.
There the toggle-animation is always missing in Firefox. I hope the solution to this simple Problem yields a hint.

Comment: working fine in firefox, http://jsfiddle.net/TX55G/5/

Comment: For me your jsfiddle link behaves as I described in Firefox:
First it works, as soon as i open the inspector and select the .inner element it doesn't.
I'm using FF33 from the ubuntu reps.
When trying to reproduce with jsfiddle, make sure, that the content of the lower-right Iframe is actually displayed in the DOM-Inspector.

Comment: I just clicked his fiddle and tried it in Firefox 33.1.1 and it worked every time.  I'm not sure what you are trying to say about the inspector, but I 'inspected' that element in the dev tools and it still worked.

Comment: My FF Version is 33.0 - not sure if that makes the difference.
About the inspector:
jsfiddle has the result embedded in an iframe, and when for the first time I tried to inspect the '.inner' element, it would somehow select it, but not display the html-content of the iframe in the inspector and the problem would not appear. However after trying a couple of times, finally the iframe content did display along with that the bug appeared.

Comment: I tested in FF 33.0.1, I've opened the inspector by selecting `.inner` and I can see the DOM. Everything works fine for me. It is animating.

Comment: Hm, I'll try some further testing then. If its not the Browser, any Idea how to figure out the actual cause?